# Which command to make multiplication like this?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Which command to make multiplication like this?

[image]

Comment: `$5*(\mathit{Mul}+2*\mathit{Add})$` ?

Comment: it  I think it does not work. The multiplication is not compiled as expected.

Comment: you should show, how you test my suggestion and what result you obtain. please, edit your question and add this information. otherwise we can't help you. my suggestion work fine to me.

Comment: Better provide MWE so it would be easier to decide which is working and which is not. Moreover, the formula you desire seems having unnecessary / inconsistent spaces (before the first asterisk and after the second one).

Comment: Do you even need to do it in math mode?  Usually this sort of thing is done using \texttt{...} or verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `\ast`: `$5 \ast (Mul + 2 \ast Add)$`

Comment: in the most of fonts `\ast` is equivalent for `*`. if op desire to have `\ast` with five lives, than (s)he should find font, which define such symbol, for example `MnSymbol`. but question is unclear ...